# How do I launch a new browser window with no toolbars?

Tags: html

I want a hyperlink on my main page to launch an HTML help page in a new browser window.  However I want the new window to only have an address bar, i.e. not have a menu, toolbars or status bar, and better still not even have an editable address bar.

I have seen this done on quite a few sites but can't figure out what I need to do to launch the new window in that state.

Any clues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand a little on what ocdecio has above, you can place the `window.open` call a function accessed from your various hyperlinks, allowing different links to pop up new windows by passing in a different argument to the function.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openWindow('faq.html');">FAQ</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openWindow('options.html');">Options</a>

<script language='Javascript'>
<!--
  // Function to open new window containing window_src, 100x400
  function openWindow(window_src)
  {
    window.open(window_src, 'newwindow', config='height=100, width=400, '
        + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
        + 'directories=no, status=no');
  }
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
<!--
window.open ('titlepage.html', 'newwindow', config='height=100,
width=400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,
location=no, directories=no, status=no')
-->
</SCRIPT>
```